# Algorithm of MSDN concurrentdictionary?

Tags: .net, concurrency, msdn, concurrent-programming

I could not locate any official information on the underlying concurrent data structure for the concurrentdictionary in .NET 4.5. Is it a skiplist or a tree or something else? Can someone give some pointer(s)?

Comment: Back in 2012 there was a whole series of articles on the concurrent collections. Here's the one on [ConcurrentDictionary](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2012/02/22/inside-the-concurrent-collections-concurrentdictionary/)

Answer (score 1):

You could just decompile it yourself to see. However this information is subject to change. If MS do not document how its implemented then they may change the implementation with any update, so it's not something that should be relied on too much.

PS JustDecompile from Telerik is free and I've had good results with it. Reflector, the original and probably still the best, is now from RedGate used to be free but isn't any more. There are other decompilers about, free and paid.